# How to formally say looking forward and keep me updated in email

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-request, formal-language, email

I emailed the repepient if they can call me. And received email from the recipient saying that their place is closed till February due to covid. But they has forwarded my request letter to higher authorities.

I want to reply them saying "thank you very much and looking forward or keep me updated" but don't know how to phrase this all formally.

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps say something like, "I am very grateful for your assistance, and eagerly await your response"